# Have a counter in SQL Server that I want to replicate in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Can anyone provide the code syntax for Oracle? I have attached the SQL Server code

```
DECLARE @count1 INT

SELECT @count1 = (SELECT COUNT(*) AS processgroupcount 
                  FROM mpp.processgroup 
                  WHERE loc = '1' AND bk = '1' AND bk_yr = '2019')

PRINT 'PROCESSGROUP RECORDS in GEN5 for loc 1, bk 1, bk_yr 2019'
PRINT @count1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE
  COUNT1 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO COUNT1
    FROM MPP.PROCESSGROUP
   WHERE LOC = '1'
     AND BK = '1'
     AND BK_YR = '2019';
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('PROCESSGROUP RECORDS IN GEN5 FOR LOC 1, BK 1, BK_YR 2019');
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(COUNT1);
END;
```